# Correct way to unpack a 32 bit vector in Perl to read a uint32 written in C

Tags: c, perl, endianness

I am parsing a Photoshop raw, 16 bit/channel, RGB file in C and trying to keep a log of exceptional data points. I need a very fast C analysis of up to 36 MPix images with 16 bit quanta or 216 MB Photoshop .RAW files.

<1% of the points have weird skin tones and I want to graph them with PerlMagick or Perl GD to see where they are coming from.

The first 4 bytes of the C data file contain the unsigned image width as a uint32_t. In Perl, I read the whole file in binary mode and extract the first 32 bits:

```
Xres=1779105792l = 0x6a0b0000
```

It looks a lot like the C log file:

```
DA: Color anomalies=14177=0.229%:
DA: II=1) raw PIDX=0x10000b25,  XCols=[0]=0x00000b6a
```

Dec(0x00000b6a) = 2922, the Exact X_Columns_Width of a small test file.

Clearly a case of intel's 1972 8008 NUXI architecture. How hard could it possibly be to translate 0x6a0b0000 to 0x6a0b0000; swap 2 bytes and 2 nibbles and you're done. Slicing the 8 characters and rearranging them could be done but that is the kind of ugly hack I am trying to avoid.

Grab the same 32 bit vector from file offset zero and unpack it as "VAX" unsigned long.

```
$xres = vec($bdat, 0, 32);  # vec EXPR,OFFSET,BITS
$vul   = unpack("V", vec($bdat, 0, 32));
printf("Length (\$bdat)=%d, xres=0x%08x, Vax ulong=%ul=0x%08x\n",
    length($bdat), $xres, $vul, $vul);
Length ($bdat) = 56712, xres=0x6a0b0000, Vax ulong=959919921l=0x39373731
```

Every single hex character is mangled. Obviously wrong Endian, it is not VAX. The "Other" one is Network Big-endian

```
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html
N  An unsigned long (32-bit) in "network" (big-endian) order.
V  An unsigned long (32-bit) in "VAX" (little-endian) order.
$nul = unpack("N", vec($bdat, 0, 32));  # Network Unsigned Long 32b
printf("Xres=0x%08x, NET ulong=%ul=0x%08x\n", $xres, $nul, $nul);
Xres=0x6a0b0000, NET ulong=825702201l=0x31373739
```

The $XRES still shows the right hex in the wrong order. The "NETWORK" long 32 bit uint extracted from the same bits is unrecognizable. Try Binary

```
$bits = unpack("b*", vec($bdat, 0, 32));
printf("bits=$bits, len=%d\n", length $bits);
   bits=10001100111011001110110010011100100011000000110010101100111011001001110001001100, len=80
```

I clearly asked for 32 bits and got 80 bits. What gives?

Try for 4, unsigned, 8bit bytes which can NOT be swapped:

```
for($ii = 0; $ii < 4; $ii++)  {
    $bit_off=$ii*8;  # Bit offset
    $uc = unpack("C", vec($bdat, $bit_off, 8));  # C  An unsigned char 
    printf("II $ii, bo $bit_off, d=%d, u=%u, x=0x%x\n", 
       $uc,$uc, $uc);
}
II 0, bo 0, d=49, u=49, x=0x31
II 1, bo 8, d=51, u=51, x=0x33
II 2, bo 16, d=49, u=49, x=0x31
II 3, bo 24, d=49, u=49, x=0x31
```

I am looking for hex 0, 6, a or b. There are no "3"s or "1"s in the right answer. Try pirating from a C file:

```
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MHX/Convert-Binary-C-0.76/tests/include/include/bits/byteswap.h
$x = $xres;
$x= (((($x) & 0xff000000) >> 24) | ((($x) & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) |     ((($x) & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) | ((($x) & 0x000000ff) << 24));
printf("\$xres=0x%08x -> \$x=0x%08x = %u\n", $xres, $x, $x);
$xres=0x6a0b0000 -> $x=0x00000b6a = 2922
```

It WORKS! But, this is uglier than converting the original, wrong order hex number to a string to untangle it:

```
$stupid_str = sprintf("%08x", $xres);
$stupid_num = join('', reverse ($stupid_str =~ m/../g));
printf("Stupid_num '%s'->0x%08x=%d\n", $stupid_num, $dec=hex $stupid_num, $dec);
Stupid_num '00000b6a'->0x00000b6a=2922
```

It's like judging the Ugliest Dog contest, but I would still rather have to maintain the text version than the even more abominable C version.

I know there are ways to do this in Java/Python/Go/Ruby/.....

I know there are command line utilities that do exactly this.

I must figure out how I am misusing either VEC or Unpack, both of which I have used a zillion times. It is the Brain Teasing aspect which is driving me nuts!  EndianNess == EndianMess!!!

TYVM!

=================================================

Borodin,

Thanks for lookin' at this.

My intel processor is little-endian. When I read it back, it was trans-mutilated by vec to the "correct" big-endian, network format.

I just tried reading it VERBATIM from a BINARY file read and it works fine:

```
($b4 = $bdat) =~ s/^(....).*$/$1/msg;   # Give me my 4 bytes back without mutilation!
printf("B4='%s'=>0x%08x=<0x%08x\n", $b4, unpack("L>", $b4), unpack("L<", $b4));
B4='j...' = >0x6a0b0000 = <0x00000b6a   <<<  THE RIGHT ANSWER!!!
```

> > If you try unpack 'V', $bdat then you will find that it works

That was my first attempt:
    $vul   = unpack("V", vec($bdat, 0, 32));  #  UNPACK V!
    printf("Length (\$bdat)=%d, xres=0x%08x, Vax ulong=%ul=0x%08x\n",
        length($bdat), $xres, $vul, $vul);
    Length ($bdat) = 56712, xres=0x6a0b0000, Vax ulong=959919921l=0x39373731   <<<< TOTALLY WRONG!

I had already verified that the $BDAT info was the right data in the wrong format. It just needed some rearrangement.

I just used vec() to generate 1 bit and 4 bit graphics files and it worked faithfully, returning the exact bits I wrote. It must have mistaken my Intel i7 for my IBM System/370. I7/37??? Easy mistake to make. :)

I read the [confusing] part about "converted to a number as with pack ...". That's why my number was backward. The >>unpack("V", vec($bdat"<< ... was my ill-fated attempt to byte-swap the backward number in $BDAT from the WRONG VEC()-preferred FORMAT to the native format supported by my architecture.

Now I understand why I saw so many examples of people extracting by the byte, to avoid Big Brother's helping hand!

```
Data::BitStream::Vec "uses a Perl vec to store the data. The vector is accessed in 1-bit units"
```

Thanks 1E6,

```
B
```

Comment: Apart from your rant (justified or not): what is your actual question and how is that related to C actually (apart from the rant, I say)?

Comment: The third argument to `vec` isn't the number of bits to translate, it is the chunk size.

Comment: The endianness of your processor is irrelevant. Your file data -- specifically the first four bytes -- are in little-endian order, and you just need to unpack them as such. I don't understand why you won't just try the `unpack 'V', $bdat` that I suggested and keep involving `vec` that you know doesn't work and I have explained why

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `vec` at all except for chunk sizes smaller than a byte

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing things by combining `vec` with `unpack`

The correct way is simply

```
unpack 'V', $bdat
```

which returns a value of `0x00000B6A` as you expect

`vec($bdat, 0, 32)` is equivalent to `unpack 'N', $bdat` as you can see from the value of `$xres` in your first code block, and the [documentation for `vec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/vec.html) confirms this with

> If BITS is 16 or more, bytes of the input string are grouped into chunks of size BITS/8, and each group is converted to a number as with pack()/unpack() with big-endian formats n/N

The line

```
$vul = unpack("V", vec($bdat, 0, 32))
```

is very wrong, because the decimal value of `vec($bdat, 0, 32)` is 1779105792, so you are then calling `unpack` on the *string* `"1779105792"` which doesn't do anything useful at all

Comment: I wanted the SAME 32 bits I wrote, VERBATIM. Vector mangles them differently depending on the length???

Comment: @BrianP007: I don't understand what you mean by *“the same 32 bits I wrote”*. `vec` will unpack multi-byte fields in a big-endian order, the same as `unpack 'N'` as I said. If you try `unpack 'V', $bdat` then you will find that it works

Comment: >>   I don't understand what you mean by “the same 32 bits I wrote”                              Earlier I had used vec() to read large 1 and 4 bit/pixel bitmaps, asking for either 1 or 4 bits at a time. The graphs I made of the 1 bit black/transparent bitmask and the 4 bit color png files crated fit the Photoshop originals perfectly.

Comment: @BrianP007: I have explained that you *can't* pass the result of `vec` to `unpack`. `vec` returns a binary value whereas `unpack`is expecting a string. `vec($bdat, 0, 32)` is *identical* to `unpack('N', $bdat)`, so `unpack('V', vec($bdat, 0, 32))` is the same as `unpack('V', unpack('N', $bdat))` which doesn't make sense as you can't stack `unpack` calls. If you would just try `unpack('V', $bdat)` *without* involving `vec` then you will have the correct result

Comment: You are so determined to be a victim that you have focussed on *“Clearly a case of intel's 1972 8008 NUXI architecture”* and *“Obviously wrong Endian, it is not VAX”* instead of the real situation, which is *“I must figure out how I am misusing either VEC or Unpack”*. Your data *is* in VAX (little-endian) order and your problem is that you don't understand what `vec` and `unpack` do: you shouldn't be using `vec` at all here.

Comment: Borodin,  With 1 and 4 bit VECtors, vec() returned exactly what the C program wrote. Crossing the 16 bit threshold, I started seeing Obvious Wrong Endianness introduced by vec(). Unpack is the standard Perl tool to fix the problem. Feeding one into the other was the problem. Small vectors still use vec() and 2+ byte packets now use unpack() without vec(). The goal of determining the root of the Misuse is accomplished. No Ugly Hacks! Thank you. But, you seem to be more agitated than necessary.  Sorry if the Endian comment struck a raw nerve <|;o

Comment: @BrianP007: I'm glad you have your solution. Rather than your comments about endianness, it was your insistence on proving me wrong without even trying my solution that jarred. Together with your attitude of blaming this nasty technology, your responses are very frustrating -- Olaf made a similar observation. By the way,  you could also unpack your bits with `unpack 'b*'` and your nybbles with `unpack `h*'`